# Export email from Outlook 365

Tags: outlook.com

How can I export a folder of emails from Outlook 365 using the web interface? (not using the Outlook PC app)

Comment: Would you consider a 3rd party desktop app such as Mozilla Thunderbird?

Comment: @Itamar Perhaps, though it would pain me to install and configure an app just for a one-time export of a folder of email messages.

Comment: Thunderbird is very nice because in addition to keeping a local copy you can move emails to another web account while maintaining the folder structure by simply moving (drag and drop) the folders to the new account.